# Multiple inheritance: only 1 parent init'd

Tags: python, python-2.7, initialization, multiple-inheritance

I cannot figure out why in the following code only one parent constructor is initialized:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Base::Base():"


class BaseWArgs(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        print "BaseWArgs::BaseWArgs(%s):" % arg


class Composite(Base, BaseWArgs):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Composite,self).__init__()
```

In this case, only Base.**init**() is called. If I switch the order of inheritance parameters, only the whatever-stands-first class is initialized:

```
class Composite(BaseWArgs, Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Composite,self).__init__('myArg')
```

How I can initialize both parents with one call? Shouldn't that be the responsibility of `super()`?

EDIT
I think my use case is a special case of multiple inheritance. I want to create an item using defaultdict as a base type, but inheriting some additional funcitonality from a third type.

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Base::Base():"
        super(Base,self).__init__()
        self.val = 'hello world'

class Item(defaultdict, Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Item,self).__init__(int)

>>> Item()
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {})

>>> Item().val
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#77>", line 1, in <module>
    Item().val
AttributeError: 'Item' object has no attribute 'val'
```

Where does `Base::Base()` get lost? Why is `Base` not initialized?

Comment: Before anyone starts linking to that "super is harmful" stuff: [Python’s super() considered super!](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)

Comment: You have to use `super` twice. `super` simply walks the `__mro__` (method resolution order) in order to find the method to call, but it *always* finds *one* method, i.e. the first one in the hierarchy.

Comment: @Bakuriu Using `super()` twice calls the same `Base.__init__()` twice.

Comment: You should read about new python classes and inheritence, that's because python don't search all parents it's take first near.

Comment: @PavloDyban Read my comment. Did I ever said to call `super` twice *with the same arguments*? I **obviously** meant to call `super` twice, with *different* arguments in order to obtain the two methods.

Comment: @Bakuriu: `super` is meant to be called with the class and instance. I don't see what "other argument" you'd want to pass in a second call in `Composite` (and _please_ don't answer `(Base, self)` or `(BaseWArgs, self)`)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers No, `super` is meant to be called with *a* class and an instance of that class, which need not be a "direct instance". Also, you can access the `__mro__` of a class in order to get the name of the parent classes (with an arbitrary complex algorithm) without explicitly mentioning them in the code.

Comment: @Bakuriu: ok the you meant manually doing some of the black magic `super` is supposed to avoid. In that case I'd rather go for an explicit call to the "uncollaborative" parent's method.

Comment: `__mro__` is an important attribute which I was not aware of when implementing complicated multiple inheritance. Thanks for pointing that out to me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither `Base.__init__` nor `BaseWArgs.__init__` implement the call to `super().__init__`, so obviously only the first one in the rmo will get called. You have to have all initializer respect the protocol for it to work.

Also, with `Base` coming first in the mro and not taking any argument, this will still fail. "collaborative" super calls require that your methods signatures are compatible. The below code do delegate the call as expected:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Base::Base():"
        super(Base, self).__init__()

class BaseWArgs(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        print "BaseWArgs::BaseWArgs(%s):" % arg
        super(BaseWArgs, self).__init__()


class Composite(BaseWArgs, Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Composite,self).__init__("foo")

c = Composite()
```

edit : wrt/ your concrete use case, it seems that `defaultdict` does not do the `super` call itself so unless it's the last in your base classes the call chain will stop there (well, it *will* stop there, but that's not a problem if it comes last ).

So you choices are either to make your whole own `Base` hierachy's initializers compatible with `defaultdict`'s one and have `defaultdict` as the last base class, or explicitely call `defaultdict`'s initializer then `Base` initializer, ie:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Base__init__():"
        super(Base, self).__init__()

class Sub(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Sub.__init__():"
        super(Sub, self).__init__()
        self.foo = "bar"


class MyClass(defaultdict, Sub):
    def __init__(self):
        defaultdict.__init__(self, int)
        Sub.__init__(self)
```

Comment: That explains why switching places between `defaultdict` & my own Base class resolved inheritance. That's because `defaultdict` does not inherit from `object` & does not implement `super().__init__()`.

Comment: @PavloDyban `defaultdict` **does** inherit from `object`, although not *directly*.

Comment: @PavloDyban : sorry sir but `defaultdict` does inherits from `object` - now I don't know whether it calls on `super` or not.

Comment: Then I am stuck again.

Comment: @PavloDyban: what's your _real_ use case ?

Comment: @ndpu: implementing the call to super in Base and BaseWArgs will make sure each class in the mro do call the next one. This won't solve potential problems with incompatible signatures.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers But not so if you derive `BaseWArgs` from e.g. `defaultdict`. `def __init__(self): super(BaseWArgs,self).__init__(int)`. Now if that class stands first in `Composite`'s order of inheritance, `Base` will not be initialized.

Comment: @PavloDyban: yes, that's because `defaultdict` will then come before `Base` in the mro and since obviously defaultdict doesn't do the `super` call the call chain stops there.